# send a String value to swf file from java

Tags: java, apache-flex, flash, blazeds

I am developing a web application in `java/j2ee`, in this project I am having two screens which are built using flex. My requirement is while clicking a table in java screen I have to send a string value to the `swf` file and load that flex page with that string value.

I am confused with how to send data from java to swf file.Please help me out in this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by java screen? is the java and flex running in the same browser window?

Answer (score 0):

Flex provides multiple ways to interact with java such as

- BlazeDS Java object access
- Http Services
- Web Services

Follow this link to learn more:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex_java.html